# General term for voting system where one group pre-selects n out of m, other selects 1 out of n?

Tags: voting, terminology, voting-systems, religion

The Wikipedia article on [Opus Dei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_Dei), the somewhat controversial, conservative institution of the Roman Catholic Church, currently explains an aspect of the institution's leadership selection procedures as follows:

> The women nominate their preferred candidates for the prelate and is
> voted upon by the men to become the next Prelate

Given the institution's (ultra-)conservative reputation this seems to be a somewhat remarkable arrangement. Can someone familiar enough with Latin please confirm that the [cited document](https://opusdei.org/en/article/statutes-of-opus-dei/) indeed spells out these terms?

And what is the general term for an (s)election procedure where two groups share power by one group pre-selecting a set of *n* out of *m* candidates and the other group then selecting 1 winner from that set?

Comment: I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but we'd generally call the first selection of n candidates a primary.

Comment: @Avi A primary is different in the sense that if this scheme were applied to U.S. elections, Republicans would first select a set of *n* (e.g. Huntsman, Perry, Romney) and Democrats would then elect 1 of *n* (e.g. Romney) for President. Or inversely, Democrats would first select a set of *n* (e.g. Clinton, Edwards, Obama) and Republicans would then elect 1 of *n* (e.g. Clinton) for President.

Comment: I understand that the US does not implement the system exactly as you described, but the definition of a primary is any election that narrows the field of candidates before a general election, so this would qualify.

Comment: @Avi The term election would also qualify. Both terms (election and primary) are too broad for what I am looking for.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure if there is a specific term for this, but if I find something, I will let you know.

Comment: This sounds like the system for presidency in Iran where the guardian council (religious leadership) must preapprove any candidates who want to run for president (in 2009 over 400 people applied and only four were approved).

Comment: IIRC, UAE has similar type of elections for their parlament.

Comment: FWIW, the Venetian Republic's electoral system to select the Doge was set up like that but with many more iterations. https://www.theballotboy.com/electing-the-doge It may have been devised contemporaneously with the Vatican system (or its predecessor along the same lines) or may have been inspired by it. This is also common in civil service systems. It is also used in Missouri Plan judicial appointment systems.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missouri_Plan

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to keep it simple and just call the process: *nomination* and *appointment*

Beyond that, I don't think there is a word for: "*Nominator proposes multiple nominees, appointer appoints only one candidate.*"

This mechanism is applied in a wide range of political contexts. The nominator controls the quality of the candidate, but the appointer has the final say on whether the candidate is granted official power. (Note, nominator usually wields more power in this dynamic.)

This is a popular way of implementing cross-institutional oversight. The idea is that since the nominator and appointer have diverging interest, they are less likely to commit collusion. The result is theoretically a more acceptable candidate for everyone.

Comment: While nomination and appointment is accurate it doesn't capture the distinctive feature of the nominator and appointer being different persons or groups of persons.

Comment: @ohwilleke I'm struck by how difficult it is to find similar examples across the world. Perhaps this arrangement is rare enough that there has yet to be a term invented for it. It's kind of understandable as most society would find it too contentious / controversial.

Answer (score 0):

*Q: General term for voting system where one group pre-selects n out of m, other selects 1 out of n?*

The Opus Dei example used to support the question is a misunderstanding of what actually happens. The terms used for participation of the "women’s council of the prelature" in the following explanations are *suggestions* <sup>[1]</sup> and *recommendations* rather than *nominat[ions]*. The system actually used may be described as:

> [TL;DR] Majority system by electoral Congress <sup>[1]</sup>.

In any case, the answer to the title question is that it may be described as a mixed system with either majority or plurality selection by an electoral body, depending on the rules for selecting the winner.

---

A prelate election was held on January 23, 2017. The process was described in [an Opus Dei article from January 15, 2017](https://opusdei.org/en-us/article/elective-congress-opus-dei-prelate/).

> The electoral process begins with a plenary meeting of the women’s council of the prelature, called the Central Advisory, which will take place starting January 21. The electoral Congress begins on January 23. In total 194 faithful of Opus Dei will participate in the process.

> In the Central Advisory, each member submits a list with the name or names of those priests in the electoral Congress seen as best suited for the position of prelate. The members of the Congress, keeping these recommendations in mind, then proceed to the voting process.

The voting and [election of the prelate](https://romana.org/en/64/the-election-of-msgr-fernando-ocariz-as-prelate-of/the-election-of-the-prelate/) completed January 23, 2017.

> Early in the afternoon on Monday the 23rd, the Elective Congress began with the plenary meetings. Once the procedures established by the specific rules of the Congress were completed, the proposals of the plenum of the Central Advisory were communicated to the members of the Congress, and following this the voting took place.
>
> The person elected was Msgr. Fernando Ocáriz Braña, till then the Auxiliary Vicar of the Prelature. The one in charge of scrutinizing the ballots, in the name of the Congress, asked him if he accepted. Msgr. Ocáriz responded affirmatively.

That the voting was by secret ballot is given from the above ("scrutinizing the ballots"). That a majority, rather than plurality, was required is inferred from the unofficial translation of the *[Statutes of Opus Dei](https://opusdei.org/en/article/statutes-of-opus-dei-eng/)*, where "excluding the system of election by compromise" suggests that plurality cannot be used.

> 130. § 1. The Prelate, who internally is called Father and whose office is for life, is chosen – excluding the system of election by compromise – by an elective General Congress convened for this purpose. His election requires the confirmation of the Roman Pontiff.

---

<sup>1</sup> An [earlier article from December 22, 2016](https://opusdei.org/en-us/article/election-of-next-prelate-to-begin-on-january-23/) used "suggestions" and "elective Congress", the latter also appearing in the translation of the *Statutes of the Opus Dei*.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the process used in civil service systems. In those systems, the person or persons who make the final selection is often called the "appointing authority", and the people selected by someone else in the first round are people on the "eligible list", and a commission establishes the eligible list. *See, e.g.* the [City and County of San Francisco's Civil Service Ordinance](https://codelibrary.amlegal.com/codes/westlake/latest/westlake_oh/0-0-0-5658#JD_rule2sec19).

Another situation when a process like this is used is on private corporations (both for profit and non-profit) where a nominations committee of the board of directors nominates candidates for open positions as directors and/or officers of the company and the nominated individuals are then voted upon by the shareholders or members of the company. In for profit companies this is typically a "Soviet ballot" with only one choice for each post (more polite terms for this are a "[closed slate](https://www.hrw.org/news/2011/05/20/un-limited-choice-marks-rights-body-election)" or a "[noncompetitive plebiscitary election](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/10.2307/2647556)") but in non-profit companies or during a "proxy fight" this is sometimes more than one person for each post. In this context, the nomination process is often not considered to be a true "voting process" even though it effectively serves that purpose, and it is customary that only the final selection is considered to be part of the true voting process.

**When there are choices for the final round voters, but they are constrained by another person or body [some political scientists call these](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/10.2307/2647556) "semicompetitive elections" or "limited-choice elections".**

These terms are used, for example, to describe the system for electing the presidency in Iran where the guardian council (religious leadership) must preapprove any candidates who want to run for president (in 2009 over 400 people applied and only four were approved), noted in the comments, and a similar system used in UAE parliamentary elections noted in the comments.

These seem to be the best terms to describe what the question is discussing.

To some extent, any system which places any administrative limitations upon who can run in an election is a limited-choice election.

The people narrowing down the choices and the ones making the final decision could be the same, as in a two round runoff election, but usually the terms "semicompetitive election" or "limited-choice election" refer to a different body narrowing the choices and making the final decision, and to a narrowing of the choices that is more than a ministerial decision of the body narrowing the choices and instead is a decision that calls for an exercise of discretion by the body narrowing the choices. This terminology has been in place since [at least the 1970s](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-349-03342-3_5). But it [continues to be used in current terminology](https://csu-sdsu.primo.exlibrisgroup.com/discovery/fulldisplay?docid=cdi_cleo_primary_oai_revues_org_chinaperspectives_787&context=PC&vid=01CALS_SDL:01CALS_SDL&lang=en&search_scope=MyInst_and_CI&adaptor=Primo%20Central&tab=Everything&query=creator,exact,%20Hairong,%20Lai%20,AND&mode=advanced).

Sometimes the term semicompetitive instead of limited choice is used when [the candidates allowed to run for office are so unequal in likelihood of success that the outcome is a foregone conclusion](https://www.infona.pl/resource/bwmeta1.element.springer-doi-10_1007-S11186-018-9328-4?&locale=en). These are also sometimes called "non-competitive elections".

Limited-choice election was also [in current use as of 1999](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2647556) and is probably the least loaded term.

Limited-choice voting should not be confused, however, with "[limited voting](https://www.nonprofitvote.org/fair-vote-methods-for-multi-seat-elections/)" which describes a practice when, for example, there are five seats to be filled at large in an election and each voter can only cast votes for two candidates to facilitate minority representation in the multimember body, rather than letting the preferences of a bare majority of voters fully control its composition.

A variety of related terms for regimes that use practices like limiting who can be considered in a  final election and other democracy restraining practices are discussed by Steven Levitsky and Lucan A. Way, in "[Elections Without Democracy: Competitive Authoritarianism](https://scholar.harvard.edu/levitsky/files/SL_elections.pdf)" 13(2) Journal of Democracy (April 2002). They note and criticize use of some of the terms that they note as too judgmental:

> recent academic writings have produced a variety of labels for mixed
> cases, including not only “hybrid regime” but also “semidemocracy,”
> “virtual democracy,” “electoral democracy,” "pseudodemocracy,”
> “illiberal democracy,” “semi-authoritarianism,” “soft
> authoritarianism,” “electoral authoritarianism,” and Freedom House’s
> “Partly Free.”

They also observe that "such labels obscure crucial differences—differences that may have important causal implications."

Some political scientists call a subset of the available choices in an election decided either conceptually by the voter or procedurally by the process for further final analysis a "[consideration set](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0261379417304262)" (in contrast to a "universal set" of all of the choices).

If only a single person or a small group of people make the final decision, it is often called an "appointment" or "selection" rather than an "election".

If one person makes a closed slate nomination and another group of people ratifies or rejects that choice, it is often called a confirmation of an appointment.

For example, if parliament presents a single choice for prime minister to the monarch, based upon its internal choice, the monarch's action is call a "confirmation" of the parliamentary election result.